# best and effective way to rename the file

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application and inside using Image resizer as a third party tool in that app. I am trying to achieve the following scenario:

I have text box (Employee Name) for example "Madona"
I have a image text box linked with third party tool "Image Resizer".

If i choose the image (eg: `Madona123.jpg`), the Image resizer will generate 17 different size images and drop it in my source folder (e.g. `Madona123_80x60.jpg`, `Madona123_150x150.jpg`, etc..)

But am trying to change the file name like e.g:  `Madona_80x60.jpg`, `Madona_150x150.jpg`

I have two options but not sure which one is effective

- Create Temp Dir from the source folder where the image is there and change the name based on the "Employee Name" and pass that image to "Image Resizer" tool
- Once the Image is generated in the destination folder,then change the file name.

Am not sure which one is best and what other concerns i have to look ,thanks for your input.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php and i do have the wrapper class around this tool.

Comment: I deleted a comment. Restored now: "What is the name of your thrd-party library".

Comment: I didn't work with the library, but hasn't the library a renaming output file facility? I know for sure, you can use MOGRIFY (if I'm not mistaken) in console mode to set different rule of how your files should be renamed. May be, you can use this technique in your C++ code?

Comment: Magick's Image object has a image's `filename` property. May be you can change it according to your needs right before invoking `resize` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your suggested scenarios I would go for option 2.

- As you stated, creating an extra temp folder might cause rights issues so if you're not entirely certain about the setup of the machines that will be using the app then option 1 might be causing your app to fail.
- As a secondary (and very minor) reason, option 2 will, even if it doesn't fail on rights still create an extra folder. If you would choose to make that temp folder part of your application, people have the tendency of removing temp folders and their contents.. Or you might create it every time on startup of the app, but that also requires, a little bit, coding. (altough point taken, this is just a minor reason and not really a reason that would tip the scales..)

I do agree with Blam's statement that option one would make the base coding a bit more simple but I think aldo the bit of extra work, option 2 will give you less possibility for failure.

So if you're gonna be using it in a manageable environment where you know the setup of your targetmachines, go with option one, it requires less and more straightforward coding, if you're gonna be using it in any other sort of environment, go with option 2. It 'll give you the highest chance of success.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 has an extra copy command - you can rename when you copy.  But with option 2 you have multiple renames.   I would do 1 for simplicity.

Comment: I do agree but if user doesn't have write access to create a temp dir in their machines then Option 1 is going to be failure,isn't it.

Comment: Yes, but since you stated it as an option I assumed they had that authority.

Comment: sorry @Blam,forgot about the security issues.In that case i do have only one option look like.